# Where are iATS configurations on CiviCRM 5.58.1?

Tags: receipts, iats, recurring

We are using CiviCRM 5.58.1 on WordPress 6.2.2

Receipts are not being sent for recurring contributions. Only on the initial contribution is a receipt sent. Today with some digging, I found this on this support forum, and this YouTube video showing this (see below screenshots), but I cannot find this configuration page on our install anywhere. Those two screenshots are specific to iATS which we are using. Can someone point me to where I can configure civicrm to send a receipt with each recurring contribution?

Thank you

[image]

[image]